# How to Sum datagridview Column by Checkbox to display on the textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need some help. I have a `DataGridView` with 9 Columns. In the first column is a `Checkbox` - if the checkbox is checked, the value is true. In the third column is `Gross Weight`. I need to sum the gross weight for each row which has a checked Checkbox and display it in `txtGW.Text`.

The value in `Gross Weight` is a double.

This is  my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < datagridviewLog.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string temp2 = datagridviewLog.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

    // if cell is 0 = true / checked
    if (temp2.ToLower() == "true") 
    {
        double sum = 0;
        sum += double.Parse(datagridviewLog.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
        txtBKselect.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use an image for showing your code, instead post the code using the code button in the toolbar.

Comment: @KarenPayne oh im sorry , im really newbie around here.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than touch cell data, consider loading your DataGridView by creating a `class` which represents the data to be displayed then assign a list of this data to a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=net-5.0) where the BindingSource becomes the DataSource for the DataGridView.

Also, using this you can access row/cell data by casting the BindingSource.Current to the type of the list.

In the following example GetCheckedButton_Click uses lambda to get selected from the BindingSource followed by `summing` the double property `Value`.

The sum is placed into a TextBox or if no rows checked the .Text property of the TextBox is emptied.

```
namespace DataGridViewCheckedSum
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly BindingSource _bindingSource = 
            new BindingSource();
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            Shown += OnShown;
        }

        private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Mocked data for demonstration of getting checked and sum
            _bindingSource.DataSource = new List<ItemRecord>()
            {
                new ItemRecord() {Selected = false, Value = 10},
                new ItemRecord() {Selected = false, Value = 5},
                new ItemRecord() {Selected = false, Value = 20},
                new ItemRecord() {Selected = false, Value = 15},
            };

            dataGridView1.DataSource = _bindingSource;
            
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "";
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 30;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Get checked from column 0, get sum of second column
        /// and display sum or nothing if nothing checked.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void GetCheckedButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var results = ((List<ItemRecord>)_bindingSource.DataSource)
                .Where(itemRecord => itemRecord.Selected).ToList();

            sumTextBox.Text = results.Count == 0 ? 
                "" : 
                $"{results.Sum(itemRecord => itemRecord.Value)}";

        }

        private void CurrentRowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_bindingSource.Current != null)
            {
                ItemRecord current = (ItemRecord)_bindingSource.Current;
                MessageBox.Show($"{(current.Selected ? "Yes" : "No")} {current.Value}");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No current row");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Place in it's own class file
    /// </summary>
    class ItemRecord
    {
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]